# Autodesk Design Automation API define Plot Settings e.g. greyscale/linewidth

Tags: plot, grayscale, autodesk-designautomation

I am searching for an option to define the Plot Settings when converting a .dwg file to a .pdf file. I want to have the converted PDF in greyscale and the linewidth of the Elements is too big. How can I define the Plotsettings in my API call to Forge Design-Automation-API?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kaliph,

regarding with plotting drawing to greyscale, as said, AutoCAD Design Automation (DA) is a kind of headless AutoCAD on the cloud. you could firstly check how local AutoCAD works with the script, then move to DA. e.g. checking '-plot' command in AutoCAD help, you would find the script would export the drawing to greyscale pdf by a plotstyle:

```
 -PLOT Y  AutoCAD PDF (General Documentation).pc3       Y Grayscale.ctb    \n
```

please note the spaces, which mean inputting default values. Grayscale.ctb is a default style of gray scale. I'd suggest you play it with local AutoCAD firstly to ensure the inputting.

If you need more flexible configuration on run-time of DA, you would need to produce your own plugin of AutoCAD by C#, VB.NET, C++, LISP.  Most requirements have to be implemented by custom commands, instead of by built-in scripts only.

Comment: Is this API command then like this?
       "Instruction": {
       "Script": "-PLOT Y  AutoCAD PDF (General Documentation).pc3       Y Grayscale.ctb    \n"
      },
If I am using this in my conversion command, I get the following message
"The property 'Instruction' does not exist on type 'ACES.Models.WorkItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."

Comment: Am I able to include this command into my workitem? Or do I have to create a new API Command to send against /Activities after the workitem is placed?

Comment: @Kaliph, yes, like that, but I do not encounter such issue before.  please post the complete test for diagnose. you could also email to forge.help@autodesk.com if some info is private.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a custom activity to do this. If you know how to do this using the `-PLOT` command on the AutoCAD command line then this will be relatively easy exercise. Here's a tutorial that shows how to create a custom activity: https://github.com/szilvaa/acadio-tutorials/blob/master/tutorial2/readme.md.

If you need help with some details then post here.

Comment: Do I have to define the -PLOT Option here?
  "Instruction": {
    "Script": "-PLOT"
  },
I can convert DWG to PDF but the line weight is to big. I want to become all lines thinner. Could be also a font weight setting. I am not so sure about this yet.

Comment: Yes, you would do it in the "Script" attribute.

Comment: Can u share the script to plott everything into greyscale. At the moment I have no clue how to define this.